# As a Polish National with no valid Polish ID, do I need a one to get married in Poland?

Tags: poland, identification, marriage

I am a multi national and hold two passports. Polish from inheritance and South African from naturalization.

I used to have a Polish ID card when I stayed in Poland for a brief while but when I moved out of Poland I had to "checkout/withdraw" my residence to avoid getting enrolled into the Army (Back then, 10 years ago, today enrollments are no longer mandatory)

I am getting married in Poland and only have a valid passport Polish passport. Is this enough or do I need some other documents too?

Comment: If you are a citizen of Poland, you have Polish ID card, and you had obligation to serve in military. Does it mean, you have resigned from Polish citizenship?

Comment: Just for clarification, you are not living in Poland at the moment, but abroad?

Comment: No more military obligation in Poland @Łukasz웃Lツ I have not resigned but instead "checked out(wymeldowac)" as permanent resident. I can still renew ID but I don't need it. Yes I am in UK, I never lived in Poland (Just during High school)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

- short form Polish birth certificate
- a valid ID (a passport will do)

If both of you are Polish citizens and never have been married before, then that's it. Things get more complicated if one doesn't have Polish citizenship. In that case foreigner is also required to provide a certificate of eligibility for marriage (note, that this is *not* same thing as certificate of being single). This certificate can usually be obtained via the consulate of the country in question. Also, if they don't speak Polish, then presence of sworn interpreter is required both when filing the papers and during the wedding.

You have to file documents with Civil Registry Office (Urząd Stanu Cywilnego) of your choosing. There is no requirement that it has to be the one with which you're registered as resident, but it sure makes the paperwork faster.

Once documents are filed and approved, you have to choose a wedding date, that is at least a month later, but no more than 6 months later (in case of civil marriage). In case of religious marriage with civil effects, you'll get certificate valid for 3 months.

For more question, check out [Warsaw's Civil Registry Office FAQ](http://usc.um.warszawa.pl/faq) (unfortunately it's only available in Polish).

Comment: Just to comment. The short form birth certificate is only valid if you were born in Poland or have had your full birth certificate officially translated and shortened to Polish archives, in case of dual nationality. Otherwise, its that easy. Not even `Dowod Osobisty` is needed.  Cost in 2014 was `84PLN` in Urzad Stanu Cywilnego

Comment: Also - Its valid for 3 Months now. Not 6 months, please change that.

Comment: @ppumkin: actually it's 6 months for civil marriage, 3 months for religious marriage with civil effect (so called "konkordat" marriage).

Comment: Ahh yes. We took konkordat. much easier.